# Need an Ambiguous example

Tags: pi, floating-point

Suppose I have a floating-point number with $m$ where $(m > 0)$ digits after the decimal point. Now if I want to round it up to $d$ where $(0 ≤ d < m)$ digits after the decimal point, sometimes I need to round up and sometimes I need to round down and sometimes nothing is needed. Sometimes the situation is ambiguous (when rounding up and down causes equal absolute error).

For example

3.141592653589790 is the given number **`Ambiguous`**

```
    3.141592653589790
    3.14159265358979 - no change
    3.1415926535897  - round up
    3.14159265358    - round up
    3.1415926535     - round up
    3.141592653      - round up
    3.14159265       - round down
    3.1415926        - round up
    3.141593         - round up
    3.14159          - round down
    .............
```

And for some of example the situation will `Ambiguous` . Can anyone give me such kind of example?

Answer (score 0):

Not super experienced with FP, but if you had a number terminating in 50, I imagine that would be ambiguous. Like 1.50 can be rounded to 2. or 3. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I also guessed that, but I am checking every digit not two or more